# How can I monitor for new files (created/moved) in a linux redhat directory using only the default tools?

Tags: linux, redhat

I'm trying to write a script that will take files from a specific directory and copy them into another directory on a Linux redhat server. The files in question would have the name abc###.doc, where the '#' would represent a number. Whenever a new file was moved or created in this directory and had the name, I would want the file to be immediately copied to another directory. For example, let's say the directory already contains these files:

```
abc001.doc
abc002.doc
abc003.doc
```

And then a new file was added, so it looks like this now:

```
abc001.doc
abc002.doc
abc003.doc
abc004.doc
```

I would want ONLY the abc004.doc file to be copied. Then, if another two files were added, such as abc005.doc and abc006.doc, then both of them would be copied as well, without the previous four files being copied.

When trying to figure out a solution to this, the first thing I looked at was **inotifywait**. However, this requires us to install it on the linux server. Unfortunately, due to security settings in our environment, we are unable to do that.

I also saw an interesting approach using python: https://askubuntu.com/questions/893019/monitor-folder-and-run-command-if-there-is-a-file-there. The problem with this, though, is that it looks for any files in there and moves them. For my specific problem, the files would not be moved from this directory, but rather copied. Therefore, it would copy all files in the abc###.doc format, not just the new ones.

The only other thing I could think to do is maybe have a list of filenames that have already been processed and just add to that as new files come in and are processed. But surely there is a more elegant way to resolve my problem...

Are there any other tools that already come with Linux that I could use to solve this issue?

Comment: Which distro are you asking about? (Linux is just a kernel and doesn't come with tools. A distribution like Ubuntu comes with tools, such as `ls` from the GNU coreutils project and `ps` from the `procps` package.)

Comment: Apologies. The distribution is redhat. I have updated the original post as well. Thanks!

Comment: So, what exactly do "the default tools" consist of?

Comment: "rpmquery -a" will tell you what is installed.  You need not have root privileges to run it.  If you are confined to an even more limited chrooted shell, we would need to know that as well and rpmquery probably wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

inotify is pretty standard on most linux systems.  The interface is provided by the kernel.  If there is a standard C compiler on the system you could build a tool very easily.  Many interpreters (perl, python, php-cli...) and Mono have interfaces as well.  There doesn't appear to be a direct interface for creating inotify watches from the shell.

If you have no tools for utilizing inotify, you will have no choice but to do polling.  The longer the delay that can be tolerated, the better.  You can use the "standard tool" **stat** to see when your directory was last modified and keep track of that, and you can use the "standard tool" **find** to see what files were changed since that time when it changes.

inotify is certainly preferred as it will just block the script with read(2) until a change is made and immediately take action.  Until I know what tools are available, I cannot present a solution for you that uses this.

A non-inotify solution follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SourceDir="/whatever"
export DestDir="/whatever else"

# assume that everything is in sync as of now
# we could save/load last_mtime in a file if this is a bad assumption
last_mtime=`stat "${SourceDir}" -c %Y`
while true; do
    new_mtime=`stat "${SourceDir}" -c %Y`
    if (( ${new_mtime} > ${last_mtime} )); then
        ls "${SourceDir}" | while read filename ; do
            if [ -f "${filename}" ]; then
                file_mtime=`stat "${filename}" -c %Y`
                if (( ${file_mtime} > ${last_mtime} )); then
                    cp "${SourceDir}/${filename}" "${DestDir}"
                fi
            fi
        done
        export last_mtime=${new_mtime}
    fi
    # wait 5 seconds before we check again
    sleep 5
done
```

you would have to run the script in the background constantly (maybe start with nohup or something).  if you could tolerate a delay of as much as 1 minute or more, you could strip out the while loop and sleep and run it with cron (assuming you have cron in your "standard tools") or even just use cron and rsync (assuming you have rsync) and no extra script.

Comment: it's an untested shell script.  sorry if there are mistakes.